# Can I use both Emacs and Vim keybindings in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I use zsh and I've recently learned `bindkey -v` binds useful Vim keybinds at once, but I also realized that, when I use `bindkey -v`, all default (Emacs-like) keybinds are disabled.

I want to use Emacs-like keybinds when I'm in the insert-mode, while Vim keybinds are also enabled when I'm in the normal-mode.

Can I use both Emacs and Vim keybinds in zsh ? And if yes, how can I do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can. It is even part of the default bindings.

To get *emacs*-like bindings for "insert-mode", you simply set *emacs* as default keymap. This is already the case, unless either of the `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` environment variables contain the string `vi` and unless you set it to *viins* explicitly with `bindkey -v`. You can also set it explicitly with `bindkey -e`.

From *emacs* mode you can then switch to *vicmd* mode ("normal-mode") with the key sequence `^X^V`, that is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. To get back to *emacs* mode just type any key sequence that would normally get you to *viins* mode ("insert-mode") with *vi*-like bindings, e.g. <kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>a</kbd>.